# using mapState in vue + typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm writing an application in vue+vuex+typescript after years of being away from vue. I get the concepts, but a lot has changed!

I'm running into a weird issue when trying to use the vuex `mapState` helper function. I have a store module called `animationCanvas`:

```
import { Module } from 'vuex'
import { RootState } from '../types'
import { AnimationCanvasState } from './types'

const state: AnimationCanvasState = {
  frames: [],
}

export const animationCanvas: Module<AnimationCanvasState, RootState> = {
  state,
}
```

And I'm pulling it into my root store module and registering it:

```
import { createStore, StoreOptions } from 'vuex'
import { RootState } from './types'
import { animationCanvas } from '@/store/modules/AnimationCanvas'

const store: StoreOptions<RootState> = {
  modules: {
    animationCanvas,
  },
}
```

When I use the store in the component pulling directly from the `$store` property it works fine:

```
import { Vue, Options } from 'vue-class-component';

@Options({
    name: 'Animation Canvas',
    computed: {
        frames() {
            return this.$store.state.animationCanvas.frames;
        },
    },
})
export default class AnimationCanvas extends Vue {
...
```

[image: works]

But when I try to add it via the `mapState` helper function I get nothing:

```
import { Vue, Options } from 'vue-class-component';
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

@Options({
    name: 'Animation Canvas',
    computed: {
        ...mapState('animationCanvas', ['frames']),
    },
})
export default class AnimationCanvas extends Vue {
```

[image: mapState not working]

And I know that module is there and named correctly, partially because it worked in the `$store` style path, but also because I can see it in the dev tools:

[image: store in dev tools]

I've been looking around in the docs but I can't quite figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere in your code I see that you have namespaced your Vuex module. I don't know the syntax for typescript but in plain JS you would do

```
const store = {
  modules: {
    animationCanvas: {
       namespaced: true,
       state: ...
    }
  }
}
```

You can check this by doing `console.log(this.$store)` in your component and seeing the structure of the object. In your getters you should have something like:

```
getters: {
   'animationCanvas/frames': ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, that was a bit of a facepalm moment :P I got tripped up when I looked at the path for `this.$store.state.animationCanvas.frames` and thought it was already namespaced. I forgot I had to actually tell the module to be namespaced. Thanks!